# Expected expression in list of expressions

Tags: ios

I read the other related errors and I have been unable to fix my problem

Please help me!

[image]

It is the common Expected expression in list of expression error.

Furthermore, I want to know if my error is connected to appdelegate.swift file.

Comment: Please post actual code as text instead of screenshots. Others can't copy and paste from your images. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
selector(MPCBrowser.requestFoundPeers(_:))
```

to:

```
#selector(MPCBrowser.requestFoundPeers(_:))
```

You forgot the `#` symbol that precedes `selector` in `#selector`.